# What is the best way to access html using Visual Basic 6?

Tags: html, vb6

I'm a beginner of Visual Basic 6.

Now, I'm trying to get the data from HTML using Visual Basic 6.
So, in HTML file, there are many tags (table, td, tr, input and so on).
I want to check the state of Checkbox (Yes or No) and then If Checkbox is checked, I want to get the data of the row which is including it.

Comment: I don't know how to read html file using VB6.

Comment: Being a beginner when it comes to programming doesn't mean that you can't use the internet. If your question is about VB6 then what's the logic in tagging the question VB.NET but not VB6 when both tags explicitly tell you not to use the wrong one?

Comment: Set a reference to `Microsoft HTML Object Library`.  You can then parse your HTML as needed.

Comment: Sample code will often have `CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` in it. So _Google_ says https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752084(v%3Dvs.85) and https://www.google.com.au/search?q=CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application"). Remember you can paste VBScript code into VBA.

Answer (score 0):

After setting a reference to "Microsoft HTML Object Library", you will be able to parse HTML fairly easily.  Here is 2 examples of how to do so.  The code in the first sample creates an HTML document and parses it.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   'create the document
   Dim doc As HTMLDocument
   Set doc = New HTMLDocument
   doc.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Heading 1</h1><h2>Heading 2</h2><h3>Heading 3</h3>"
    
   'access elements
   Dim c As IHTMLElementCollection
   Set c = doc.getElementsByTagName("h2")
   MsgBox c(0).innerHTML
End Sub
```

The code in the second sample loads an HTML document from the hard drive and parses it.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command2_Click()
   'load the document
   Dim htm As HTMLDocument
   Set htm = New HTMLDocument

   Dim doc As HTMLDocument
   Set doc = htm.createDocumentFromUrl("c:\temp\test.htm", "")  'contains a table

   'wait for it to be ready
   Do While doc.readyState <> "complete"
      DoEvents
   Loop
   
   'access 2nd row in table (taking into account the column headers)
   Dim c As IHTMLElementCollection
   Set c = doc.getElementsByTagName("tr")
   MsgBox c(2).innerHTML
End Sub
```